# How can I get wireless working on an HP-Mini 110-3150?

Tags: 10.10, wireless, drivers, hp

I just got an HP Mini 110-3150, and booting from an external hard disk with Ubuntu 10.10 works all fine, except that there is no wireless detected. I noticed that the Wireless indicator is red under Ubuntu, but is enabled under whatever Windows 7 I got on it. So, I understand that it may not get detected at all by Ubuntu at startup time, and there is no manual switch that I can simply slide to turn on/off.

How can I get the Wireless device turned ON by default at startup time, and is there any special driver I need to install (proprietary or not) to get it working ?

Merci :-)

Update: When actually installing on the computer, as a new install, the NIC is not detected at first, but upon restarting, I get a notification of a closed driver available for the wireless. Once installed, updated and restarted, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks#HP%20Mini%20110%20/%20Compaq%20Mini%20100c/110c) for 10.04 you need to install the wireless drivers separately.

We need more information about your system, if you can [add some log information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) to your question it would help determine exactly what (and wouldn't break anything more).

> Everything works out of the box but the recommended Broadcom STA driver does not appear to activate in live mode. Furthermore, on booting after installation a blank screen appears with a flashing cursor due to this issue. The workaround for this is to press Shift on reboot until the GRUB menu appears and select the recovery mode, followed by the fail safe graphics mode. Once booted into this low resolution mode, a standard restart should allow the computer to boot normally, but it many not boot properly on further attempts which is why it's imperative to immediately plug in an ethernet cable and enter the following two terminal commands to install the STA driver:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and then reboot.

Comment: I just restarted it with a live USB disk and a wired connection, and this time, I got the message about a "proprietary driver available". I'm getting the driver downloaded right now. This may solve my whole problem.

Comment: @jfmessier If it works add an answer and accept it so the next person with this hardware can benefit. (If it doesn't work just update your question).

Comment: Done in the original qestion. I also accepted your answer, as it makes much sense and was documented for my actual wireless card.